# pandas: join dataframe on condition in next row

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas data frame df1 that follows a chronological order where "id" is unique:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 17], [1, 5], [2, 11], [3, 15], [4, 10]], columns = ['seq', 'id'])

seq    id
  0    17
  1     5
  2    11
  3    15
  4    10
```

I need to join data from another data frame df2 where "id" can appear many times in the "id_1" column, but where the id1-id2 combination is unique:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[17, 7, 'a'], [17, 5, 'b'], [17, 8, 'c'], [5, 4, 'd'], [5, 11, 'e'], [11, 9, 'f'], [11, 15, 'g'], [15, 21, 'h'], [15, 10, 'i']], columns = ['id_1', 'id_2', 'x1'])

id_1   id_2    x1
  17      7     a
  17      5     b
  17      8     c
   5      4     d
   5     11     e
  11      9     f
  11     15     g
  15     21     h
  15     10     i
```

The result joined to df1 should be based on the next row. For example, for the first row where seq=0, the data from df2 must be joined only if id_1 = id & id_2 = id on the next row at seq=1. The final result, should be like so:

```
seq    id    x1
  0    17     b
  1     5     e
  2    11     g
  3    15     i
  4    10
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: You could use [Shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get the necessary columns to line up, then join on the original column and the shifted one.

Comment: Liam's solution is probably the best. Make a new column: `df1['id_2'] = df1['id'].shift(-1)` and them merge on `id_1`, `id_2`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, works great!